# Reading txt file contents and storing in array

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have been trying to read a txt file. The txt file contains lines e.g

```
First Line
Second Line
Third Line
.
.
.
```

Now I am using following code

```
InputStream is = null;
try {
    is = getResources().getAssets().open("myFile.txt");
} catch (IOException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}

ArrayList<String> arrayOfLines = new ArrayList<String>();

Reader reader;
//char[] buffer = new char[2048];
try {
    Reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"));
    int n;
    while   ((n = reader.read()) != -1) {

    }
}catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

My question is, how can i store each line in the arrayList. Ofc We have to use a check for `"/n"` but how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could alternatively use the [`Scanner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) class.

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(new File("/path/to/file.txt"));
while(in.hasNextLine()) {
    arrayOfLines.add(in.nextLine());
}
```

You don't have to worry about `\n`, since [`Scanner.nextLine()` will skip the newline.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine%28%29)

Comment: It is storing words only not full line.

Answer (score 2):

This code should work.

```
 ArrayList<String> arrayOfLines = new ArrayList<String>();
 FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("myfile.txt");
  DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
  String strLine;
  while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)   {
  arrayOfLines.add(strLine);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
int n;
while   ((n = reader.read()) != -1) {

}
```

Should probably look more like this:

```
String line = reader.readLine();
while   (line!=null) {
    arrayOfLines.add(line);
    line = reader.readLine();
}
```

Since you are using a `BufferedReader`, you should be calling `readLine()` instead of reading into a char buffer. The `Reader` declaration also needs to be `BufferedReader`.

Comment: @umar you need to change your `Reader reader` into `BufferedReader reader`